# How to add interactive buttons in Applozic mesasge?

Tags: android, applozic

At applozic site https://www.applozic.com/messaging-api-use-cases.html interactive shopping assistant is presented. But in documentation is no example how to add buttons and etc to the messages. Please deliver an example of how to achieve such result.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't provide on-demand tutorials or code, here.

Comment: Your verbiage comes off as "Do this for me", but yet it is more of a request to applozic to improve their documentation. It seems applozic does suggest to post to SO for help. Remove "Please deliver an example of how to achieve such result." and replace it with "is it possible to do this through the api?"

Comment: @CodyG. It would still be an off-topic question. The op has no code and/or logcat to show us for fixing.

Comment: Applozic use SO as support platform. From applozic.com "We provide quick support at StackOverflow when you tag using applozic."

Comment: /help/on-topic suggests that questions do not require code, although I see resentment by many people for questions that don't. help/how-to-ask suggests "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague"  --- and in this case if your busy colleague knows applozic this question is perfect, just worded such that your colleague might frown at you until you go away.

Answer (score 1):

Message contains metadata which is a key value pair.
https://www.applozic.com/docs/platform-api-chat.html#message-metadata

In order to build interactive button, you need to send the message along with metadata and then on the UI code side, parse the meta data and render the UI accordingly.